# Centering ListBoxItem content horizontally and vertically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listboxitem

I'm trying to center the content of my ListBoxItem vertically and horizontally but I can't get it to work.

My style template :

```xml
<Style x:Key="myListBoxItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="2" Direction="90" BlurRadius="4" Color="Black" Opacity="0.25"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#fe3f3f"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="DemiBold"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#e9e9e9"/>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="160"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="19"/>
</Style>
```

Here is how I apply this style : I have a simple ListBox in my XAML, and I append ListBoxItems to it in code-behind. I set the ResourceReference of each ListBoxItem to my style this way :

```cs
foreach (var equipment in listEquipments)
{
      var lbi = new ListBoxItem();
      lbi.Content = equipment.Name;
      lbi.SetResourceReference(StyleProperty, "myListBoxItem");
      ListBox_Equipments.Items.Add(lbi);
}
```

I've tried to set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` and `HorizontalContentAlignment` of the ListBoxItem (through the style template) to `Center`, as well as the `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`, but nothing succeeded. I thought it might have to do with my style template.

I also tried some ItemTemplates such as :

```xml
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="72"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

No luck so far.

Comment: So where and how is the Style that you have posted applied? Also, an `ItemTemplate` doesn't get applied to `ListBoxItems`.

Comment: I have a ListBox in my XAML and I'm appending ListBoxItems to it in code-behind. Then, I set these ListBoxItems' ResourceReference to my StyleProperty.

Comment: I added the way that I apply my style to the ListBoxItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ItemTemplate` is not applied to a `ListBoxItem`.

Set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `ListBox` to your `listEquipments`:

```
ListBox_Equipments.ItemsSource = listEquipments;
```

...and set the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ListBox` to your custom `Style`:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox_Equipments"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myListBoxItem}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an error when adding the ListBoxItem to the ListBox : "Operation is not valid when ItemsSource is currently being used"

Comment: Yes, because you shouldn't do this...didn't you read my answer? See the first code snippet. It replaces your entire `foreach`. Do not create any `ListBoxItem` explicitly in your code. Instead, set the `ItemsSource ` to your `listEquipments` as per above.

Comment: Alright my bad, I replaced it but now no items are added to the ListBox. Entire function :
`private void FillPanelEquipement(List<Equipement> listEquipments) {
Grid arrayGridNeed = EquipementArray as Grid;
arrayGridNeed.Children.Clear();

ListBox_Equipments.ItemsSource = lstEquipments;
if (ListBox_Equipments.Items.Count > 0)
    (ListBox_Equipments.Items[0] as ListBoxItem).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ListBoxItem.SelectedEvent));
}`

Comment: `arrayGridNeed` is a grid which holds the details of the equipments in a table according to the ListBoxItem of my ListBox that has been selected. `lstEquipments` has to contain something since it worked and displayed data with the foreach beforehand.

Comment: Then it should work now as well. Debug to find out what `ListBox_Equipments.Items.Count` returns.

Comment: I fixed it. The problem was my selection of the first item in the ListBox, my last line of code in the function above.
Now, with this method, do you know if it would be possible to select the first item of the ListBox at first ? (to display data without requiring the user to click)

Comment: That's another question. Please close this one by accepting the answer when your original issue has been solved and then create another question if you have another issue.